# Alternate multicolumn

Tags: tables

Is there a nice way to use `\multicolumn` in alternate rows in a table. i.e.,

```
\begin{tabular}{| l  r |}
\hline
  item 1  & item 2\\
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{item3}\
  item 1  & item 2\\
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{item3}\
  item 1  & item 2\\
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{item3}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Expected output:

[image]

Comment: You can define `\newcommand{\C}[1]{\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{#1}` and use `\C{item3}`.

Comment: or if you want to think of it as a layout for a three item row, define `\newcommand\abc[3]{#1&#2\\\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{#3}\\}` then `\abc{item 1}{\item 2}{item 3} \abc{item 1}{\item 2}{item 3}..` ...

Comment: @david-carlisle, your idea is a nice one. Is it possible to do it with 'collcell' by applying 'multicol' to the third column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is some code that will only work if every line ends with `\\`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\def\newlinemulticol#1\\%
  {%
    \omit\\%
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{#1}\\%
  }
\begin{tabular}{cc<{\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\newlinemulticol}c}
  Hello, world & Cheers & Middle \\
  abc & def & mid \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

But really, you should use `\collectcell`.

Comment: Can you please explain why are so many \afrergroup required.

Comment: @anandogc The `c` column in a tabular roughly means `\hskip\tabcolsep{\hfil\ignorespaces#\unskip\hfil}\hskip\tabcolsep`, where `#` stands for the cell contents, `\hskip\tabcolsep`, `\hfil`, `\ignorespaces` and `\unskip` have to do with spacing.  The group, `{...}` is there to match the `array` environment, where the math mode `$...$` creates a group.  `<{...}` puts its material after `#`, hence my three `\aftergroup` go inside the group.  The first puts the second after `}`. The third puts the `\newlinemulticol` after `}`. The remaining `\aftergroup` moves the macro after `&` where it belongs.